# Could the Praxeology of the ASoE win the battle against the scientist agenda?

Tags: philosophy-of-economics

#### Introduction

The Austrian School of Economics calls its method praxeology what is considered a branch of philosophy, and considers economics as a branch of philosophy (Rothbard, 2019).

The ASoE has proved itself useful predicting the great depression, the dot-com bubble and the fall of the system of Bettron Woods as some examples ("Austrian predictions"). Thus being a branch of philosophy proving philosophy useful.

The ASoE is mainly attacked under the scientism claim of "The empirical science is the source of knowledge". (Being this the foundation the virtually all the critics against this school of ecnomic tought).

---

#### Question

Could the Praxeology of the ASoE win the battle against the scientist agenda?

---

Rothbard, Murray N.. (2019, 11 07). Praxeology: The Methodology of Austrian Economics. Mises Institute. https://mises.org/library/praxeology-methodology-austrian-economics

Austrian predictions. (2021, October 31). In Mises Wiki. https://wiki.mises.org/mediawiki/index.php?title=Austrian_predictions&oldid=3011

Comment: One does not need to believe that empirical science is the only source of knowledge to doubt that Kant's pure intuition and synthetic *a priori* are a shaky basis for developing economics. It is probably more productive to move away from ideological "battle of agendas" to more pragmatic approaches. As [Linsbichler](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s11229-019-02150-8) writes:"*Mainstream economists and philosophers might be more likely to engage in fruitful discussions with those Austrian scholars who elaborate pragmatic arguments for praxeology instead of invoking pure intuition.*"

Comment: FI you are pragmatic, you are just thinking in useful fiction and no knowledge.

Comment: It's not paxeology but praxeology deriving from the greek *praxis*, meaning action.

Comment: Maybe consider some less biased sources than a wiki manifestly set up by fan boys of the ASoE founder?

Comment: @armand Ludwig von Mises is no the Founder of the ASoE, the founder is Carl Menger and Ludwig von Mises is a great contributor to the School.

Comment: Why does one of the citations link to a blank page?

Comment: @Sandejo Sorry, my mistake, I have already corrected it.

Comment: cisntism = Scientism? "Therefore proving philosophy as a uselful disipline" Because predictive power is the *only* arbiter of that, you think, for all subjects? Really garbled, badly formatted question.

Comment: @CriglCragl. First of all I have corrected that spelling mistale. Second if true that predictive power is o the only arbiter of that, but for scientisms it is virtually the only arbiter of that.

Comment: “betran woods” should read “Bretton Woods”.

Answer (score 3):

George Reisman, who agrees with most of the Austrian economists' economic ideas, disagrees with praxeology. Reisman's position is that economics is about how wealth is created under the division of labour. Trying to extend it to all choices doesn't help solve economic problems in that sense and it doesn't solve any other problems either, so what's the point?

For a discussion of praxeology with quotes from Reisman and Mises, see

https://conjecturesandrefutations.com/2020/11/23/reisman-and-praxeology/

Comment: In what he disagree?, there is something that are really important in the Austrian School of economy.

Comment: I explained the disagreement in the post and in more detail in the link.

Comment: The link talks about the disagreement in the foundation of economy, but no about disagreement in results. And I want to know what is the disagreement in the last.

Answer (score -1):

Wikipedia states that von Mises developed his theory with reference to Kant, Weber and Menger.

> However, the philosopher of science Mario Bunge dismissed that praxeology as "nothing but the maximisation of subjective utility - a fancy version of egoism." Bunge, who was a fierce critic of pseudo-science warned that when "concieved in extremely general terms and detached from both ethics and science, praxiology has hardly any practical value."

So probably not.

Comment: Subjective utility, is subjective, therefore one can see altruism as maximisation of their own utility. Therefore it cannot be a fancy form of egoism.